# Covering up a small mistake in flooring

Tags: flooring

I installed some engineered click-lock hardwood for the first time, and I made a small mistake, I made a bad cut and the edge is a bit far from the wall. I expect I will have to pull them out and install a new piece in that spot, which isn't a huge deal, but is there an easier way to fix it? Like would it look right if I just glued down a strip?

Comment: It's a piece running along a wall, I just accidentally cut it too narrow and  didn't think it would matter because I thought the trim would hide it. I'm a bit embarrassed it even happened to be honest; I had been laying them down for hours at that point and was just trying to hurry up and get it done.

Comment: Okay I appreciate that. I'll just pay for being lazy about it in the first place. It's a floating install so it's not a huge thing to pull them up since everything else is already placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to secure a thin strip like that with less effort than simply replacing the faulty board. You'll regret not fixing it correctly.